# PHP error_log outputting line breaks as literal "\n" strings on Mac OSX

Tags: php, macos, terminal

I'm working on some code that uses `error_log()` for debugging. The problem is that for some reason, all of the line breaks in the output appear as literal `\n` strings, so there's no actual line break (making it damn near impossible to comprehend complex arrays).
I tried using both `var_export` and `print_r` with the `error_log` function, and both led to the same result: a block of text with `\n` scattered throughout. I even tried doing `str_replace` `\n` to `PHP_EOL` with no success. What am I doing wrong?

To clarify: the `\n` strings appear in the Console error log viewer, TextEdit, and the Terminal.

**EDIT**

Just wanted to note in advance that yes, I'm aware that you need to double-quote `\n` strings for them to appear as line breaks. However, I'm dealing with the output from `print_r` or `var_export` (to inspect an array) so this doesn't really help me (I think?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, this issue is independent of your operating system. See this question: [PHP error log and newline chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203664/php-error-log-and-newline-chars)

> ...you should be able to change the error_log directive in your php.ini on Debian to point to a file. If this is undefined, it will go through syslog which doesn't support multiple lines.

Comment: Note also that for Apache to write newlines to error.log, it will need write permissions to do so (else syslog will end up writing to error.log instead). Perms fix or new file 'php-errors.log' if you want to preserve syslog format for Apache's errors (my preference).

Answer (score 36):

As an alternative, you can process / replace the '\n' via `sed`, so they display like new lines in the console:

**Linux**

```
$ tail -f error_log | sed "s/\\\n/\\n/g"
```

**Mac OS X**

```
# WARNING - don't just copy+paste (see comment below)
$ tail -f error_log | sed "s/\\\n/^M^L/g"
```

Note: In Mac OS X, the end of a line is `CRLF` (Carriage Return Line Feed) when in LINUX system it's only `LF` (Line Feed)

Note 2: In Mac OS X to output `^M` in the Terminal, press `Control+V Control+M`, to output `^L`, press `Control+V Control+L`

Comment: What OSX version. Mavericks?

Comment: For other lazy people like me: Don't just copy and paste the Mac OS X command. You must actually type it out, at least the `^M^L` part as Note 2 explains. Thanks 8y5, nice solution!

Comment: Is there a way to save this as an alias?