# OSX PHP error log not using line breaks

Tags: php, macos, line-breaks, error-log

First off, I just want to say that I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319123/php-error-log-outputting-line-breaks-as-literal-n-strings-on-mac-osx) and it didn't help. Here's my situation:

I'm using vhosts as configured in `/etc/apache2/extra`, and I have this in each entry:

```
ErrorLog "/path/to/error_log"
```

The error_log commands absolutely write to the proper error logs and properly ignores the `error_log` location in `php.ini`, but any line breaks appear as `"\n"` and the text from the arrays just run on; I really need it to be formatted properly.

Is there a way to enable real line breaks in error logs when using separate locally-hosted sites, or am I just going to have to deal with this? FWIW, this happens for me on both my OSX Lion and OSX Yosemite machines. The aforementioned thread, btw, specifically addresses using the default `error_log` location as directed in `php.ini`, which again, is not what I'm doing.

Comment: How are you viewing these logs?

Comment: I've tried the OSX preview function (that is, highlight the file and hit the space bar) -- which is the way I'd prefer to do it, it's quick and easy and doesn't require any terminal input that pushes up some vital info I need to look at -- but I also tried TextEdit, TextWrangler, and Console.

Comment: Seriously? Why the down vote on this? I could not find an answer to this or else I wouldn't have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution, thanks to macrumors.com!

In the httpd-vhosts.conf file, in the entry for the site, I need to add this command:

```
php_value error_log "/path/to/error.log"
```

Then do a `chown www` on the file.

Success!