# I'm having an error by using the error_log php function

Tags: php

I've got a problem.

```
$log = error_log("/r/n $date, $username, $error", 3, "logs/login.txt");
```

I want a linebreak whenever a new error is send to the log.

but the log outputs:

```
2013-08-17 13:10:34, asdf, Logingegevens onjuist! /r/n2013-08-17 13:10:41, fffffff, Logingegevens onjuist!
```

what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

From the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1203867/1438393):

> ...you should be able to change the error_log directive in your php.ini on Debian to point to a file. If this is undefined, **it will go through syslog which doesn't support multiple lines**.

This may happen if:

- Apache can't write to into your `error_log` file
- The `error_log` directive is empty

If it's the former, then you should be able to fix this by defining a file using the `error_log` directive in `php.ini`.

If it's the latter, then you can change the CHMOD permissions for that file and give Apache write access.

Documentation: [**`error_log()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using file logging then this won't work.

Otherwise, it's `\r\n`, not `/r/n`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't script in php for long.. so first thanks for the replies.

The code I used now was:

```
$log_data = "$date, $ip, $username, $error \r\n";
$log = file_put_contents("logs/login.log", $log_data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

with these variables:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip = GetHostByName("REMOTE_ADDR");
```

wich outputs: (ip blurred)

```
2013-08-19 13:28:28, x7.2xx.x5.x32, Vul alles in aub! 
2013-08-19 13:28:54, x7.2xx.x5.x32, Vul alles in aub! 
2013-08-19 13:28:58, x7.2xx.x5.x32, Vul alles in aub! 
2013-08-19 13:29:34, x7.2xx.x5.x32, admin, Login Succesvol! 
2013-08-19 13:35:02, x7.2xx.x5.x32, admin, Login Succesvol! 
2013-08-19 14:58:37, x7.2xx.x5.x32, admin Succesvol Uitgelogt!  
2013-08-19 14:58:44, x7.2xx.x5.x32, Paul, Logingegevens onjuist! 
2013-08-19 14:58:50, x7.2xx.x5.x32, admin, Login Succesvol!
```

again: Thnx all

(sorry for bad English, I'm from Holland)