# Apache - PHP errors logged with escaped n

Tags: php, apache

Basically the same problem as this question but the suggested fixes are not working:

[PHP error log and newline chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203664/php-error-log-and-newline-chars)

Error logs are being written by Apache like this:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/www/logs/error_log.%Y-%m-%d 86400"
```

But the PHP errors in the logs are full of `\n` where there should be a new line.

I have tried setting the ownership of the logs folder and the logs file to "apache" as suggested in the other question but this doesn't help.

The server is running php-fpm. Note if I chose to use php-fpm logging `php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log` then the logs that are created are correct, but this is a general log and not suitable for the server running multiple sites.

Comment: We have the same issue and my understanding was it's either XDebug or New Relic. It is very annoying. It is also a shared environment.

Comment: So what ownership do the created log files have?

Comment: Usually root but I also tried apache:apache